# The projection from the universal closed scheme is surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to S$ be a projective flat morphism of finite presentation, $H$ the Hilbert scheme, and $W \subseteq X \times_S H$ the universal closed subscheme.
Then is the projection $ p : W \to H$ surjective?

In Bosch, Lutkebohmern, Raynaud's "Neron models", the authors say that "Due to the definition of $\operatorname{Hilb}_{X/S}$, the map $p$ is faithfully flat, proper, and finitely presented".
But by the definition, we only have that $p$ is flat proper of finite presentation.
Why is this $p$ surjective?

I want to use the fppf descent for a closed subscheme of $W$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Let $T$ be an $S$-scheme and let $Z$ be a $T$-point of $H$. Then, by definition, this corresponds to a closed subscheme $W_Z$ of $X_T$ (flat over $T$), and moreover this closed subscheme is the pull-back of $T\to H$ along $W\to H$. Thus, the fiber of $W\to H$ over  $Z$ as an object of $H(T)$ is just $W_Z$ (hence the notation...).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks you. But I think the empty scheme is flat and closed over any schemes.

Comment: are you worried that $W_Z$ is empty? The $T$-point corresponds by definition to a closed subscheme of $X_T$ with a certain Hilbert polynomial. It is  not empty if you choose this Hilbert polynomial appropriately.